# Visual Studio: unresolved import 'numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to run the code below which requires numpy. I installed it via `pip install numpy`. However, numpy gets highlighted in the editor with the note *unresolved import 'numpy'*. When I try to run it I get the error *No module named 'numpy'*. After I got the error the first time I uninstalled numpy and re-installed it but the problem persists.

I am using Python 3.7.8 and NumPy 1.20.2.

The code I am trying to run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
# Copyright (c) 2018 Matthew Earl
# 
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
# 
#     The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
#     in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
# 
#     THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
#     OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
#     MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN
#     NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM,
#     DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR
#     OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE
#     USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.


"""
Super Mario Bros level extractor
This script requires py65emu, numpy, and PIL to run.  Run with no arguments to see usage.
See http://matthewearl.github.io/2018/06/28/smb-level-extractor/ for a description of how this was written.
To run you'll need to compile https://gist.github.com/1wErt3r/4048722 with x816 to obtain the PRG-ROM and symbol files.
The CHR-ROM should be extracted from a Super Mario Bros ROM, or can be read from an INES ROM file.  See
https://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/INES for information on the INES format.  In addition you'll need a NES palette
saved in "data/ntscpalette.pal", generated using the tool here: https://bisqwit.iki.fi/utils/nespalette.php
"""


import collections
import pathlib
import re

import numpy as np

from py65emu.cpu import CPU
from py65emu.mmu import MMU


_WORKING_RAM_SIZE = 0x800


Symbol = collections.namedtuple('Symbol', ('name', 'address', 'line_num'))


class SymbolFile:
    _LINE_RE = r"(?P<name>[A-Z0-9_]+) *= \$(?P<address>[A-F0-9]*) *; <> \d+, statement #(?P<line_num>\d+)"
    def __init__(self, fname):
        with open(fname) as f:
            self._symbols = [self._parse_symbol(line) for line in f.readlines()]

        self._symbols = list(sorted(self._symbols, key=lambda s: s.address))
        self._name_to_addr = {s.name: s.address for s in self._symbols}
        self._addr_to_name = {s.address: s.name for s in self._symbols}

    def _parse_symbol(self, line):
        m = re.match(self._LINE_RE, line)
        return Symbol(m.group('name'), int(m.group('address'), 16), int(m.group('line_num')))

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self._name_to_addr[name]


def _read_ppu_data(mmu, addr):
    while True:
        ppu_high_addr = mmu.read(addr)
        if ppu_high_addr == 0x0:
            break
        ppu_low_addr = mmu.read(addr + 1)
        assert ppu_high_addr == 0x3f and ppu_low_addr == 0x00
        flags_and_length = mmu.read(addr + 2)
        assert (flags_and_length & (1<<7)) == 0, "32-byte increment flag set"
        assert (flags_and_length & (1<<6)) == 0, "Repeating flag set"
        length = flags_and_length & 0b111111

        addr += 3
        for i in range(length):
            yield mmu.read(addr)
            addr += 1


def _load_palette(mmu, sym_file, nes_palette):
    area_type = mmu.read(sym_file['AREATYPE'])
    idx = mmu.read(sym_file['AREAPALETTE'] + area_type)

    high_addr = mmu.read(sym_file['VRAM_ADDRTABLE_HIGH'] + idx)
    low_addr = mmu.read(sym_file['VRAM_ADDRTABLE_LOW'] + idx)

    palette_data = list(_read_ppu_data(mmu, high_addr << 8 | low_addr))
    assert len(palette_data) == 32

    a = np.array(palette_data[:16]).reshape(4, 4)
    a[:, 0] = mmu.read(sym_file['BACKGROUNDCOLORS'] + area_type)
    
    return nes_palette[a]


def _execute_subroutine(cpu, addr):
    s_before = cpu.r.s
    cpu.JSR(addr)
    while cpu.r.s != s_before:
        cpu.step()


def _get_metatile_buffer(mmu, sym_file):
    return [mmu.read(sym_file['METATILEBUFFER'] + i) for i in range(13)]


def load_tile(chr_rom, idx):
    chr_rom_addr = 0x1000 + 16 * idx
    d = chr_rom[chr_rom_addr:chr_rom_addr + 16]
    a = np.array([[b & (128 >> i) != 0 for i in range(8)] for b in d]).reshape(2, 8, 8)
    return a[0] + 2 * a[1]


def _render_metatile(mmu, chr_rom, mtile, palette):
    palette_num = mtile >> 6
    palette_idx = mtile & 0b111111

    high_addr = mmu.read(sym_file['METATILEGRAPHICS_HIGH'] + palette_num)
    low_addr = mmu.read(sym_file['METATILEGRAPHICS_LOW'] + palette_num)

    addr = (high_addr << 8 | low_addr) + palette_idx * 4

    t = np.vstack([np.hstack([load_tile(chr_rom, mmu.read(addr + c * 2 + r)) for c in range(2)])
                        for r in range(2)])

    return palette[palette_num][t]


def load_level(stage, prg_rom, chr_rom, sym_file, nes_palette):
    # Initialize the MMU / CPU
    mmu = MMU([
            (0x0, _WORKING_RAM_SIZE, False, []),
            (0x8000, 0x10000, True, list(prg_rom))
    ])
    cpu = CPU(mmu, 0x0)

    # Execute some preamble subroutines which set up variables used by the main subroutines.
    if isinstance(stage, tuple):
        world_num, area_num = stage
        mmu.write(sym_file['WORLDNUMBER'], world_num - 1)
        mmu.write(sym_file['AREANUMBER'], area_num - 1)
        _execute_subroutine(cpu, sym_file['LOADAREAPOINTER'])
    else:
        area_pointer = stage
        mmu.write(sym_file['AREAPOINTER'], area_pointer)

    mmu.write(sym_file['HALFWAYPAGE'], 0)
    mmu.write(sym_file['ALTENTRANCECONTROL'], 0)
    mmu.write(sym_file['PRIMARYHARDMODE'], 0)
    mmu.write(sym_file['OPERMODE_TASK'], 0)
    _execute_subroutine(cpu, sym_file['INITIALIZEAREA'])

    # Extract the palette.
    palette = _load_palette(mmu, sym_file, nes_palette)

    # Repeatedly extract meta-tile columns, until the level starts repeating.
    cols = []
    for column_pos in range(1000):
        _execute_subroutine(cpu, sym_file['AREAPARSERCORE'])
        cols.append(_get_metatile_buffer(mmu, sym_file))
        _execute_subroutine(cpu, sym_file['INCREMENTCOLUMNPOS'])

        if len(cols) >= 96 and cols[-48:] == cols[-96:-48]:
            cols = cols[:-80]
            break
    level = np.array(cols).T

    # Render a dict of metatiles.
    mtiles = {mtile: _render_metatile(mmu, chr_rom, mtile, palette)
                for mtile in set(level.flatten())}

    return level, mtiles


def render_level(level, mtiles):
    return np.vstack([np.hstack([mtiles[mtile] for mtile in row]) for row in level])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    import PIL.Image

    world_map = {
        '{}-{}'.format(world_num, area_num): (world_num, area_num)
            for world_num in range(1, 9)
            for area_num in range(1, 5)
    }
    world_map.update({
        'bonus': 0xc2,
        'cloud1': 0x2b,
        'cloud2': 0x34,
        'water1': 0x00,
        'water2': 0x02,
        'warp': 0x2f,
    })

    if len(sys.argv) < 6:
        print("Usage: {} <world> <prg-rom> <sym-file> <chr-rom> <out-file>".format(sys.argv[0]), file=sys.stderr)
        print("  <world> is one of {}".format(', '.join(sorted(world_map.keys()))), file=sys.stderr)
        print("  <prg-rom> is the binary output from x816")
        print("  <sym-file> is the sym file output from x816")
        print("  <chr-rom> is a CHR-ROM dump")
        print("  <out-file> is the output image name")
        sys.exit(-1)

    stage = world_map[sys.argv[1]]
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'rb') as f:
        prg_rom = f.read()
    sym_file = SymbolFile(sys.argv[3])
    with open(sys.argv[4], 'rb') as f:
        chr_rom = f.read()
    out_fname = sys.argv[5]

    with (pathlib.Path(sys.argv[0]).parent / "data" / "ntscpalette.pal").open("rb") as f:
        nes_palette = np.array(list(f.read())).reshape(64, 3)

    level, mtiles = load_level(stage, prg_rom, chr_rom, sym_file, nes_palette)
    a = render_level(level, mtiles).astype(np.uint8)
    im = PIL.Image.fromarray(a)
    im.save(out_fname)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you create your workspace in Visual Studio? Do you have Python development tools installed with Visual Studio? Did you create a "Python application" as your project template?

If so then your project should have a virtual environment created, which you can see in the solution directory. If that is the case do:

1. Go to "Solution Explorer" Tab >
2. Find "Python Environments"
3. Find your active env. For me there was only one called "Python 3.9 (global default)"
4. Right click and select "Manage Python Packages..."

There it should list all the packages installed and versions. If numpy is not there, just type "numpy" in the search box and click the suggests install option: "run command: pip install numpy".

Comment: Thanks that really helped. Turned out that numpy was only installed for the 32-Bit version but I was using the 64-Bit one

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed NumPy in the same python environment that you use to run the program. (Check the PATH variable if it includes the path to the correct python environment)

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem. I installed pynput the same way and that works just fine. But I can give it a try. How do I do that? Where is that PATH variable?

Comment: Like I said that wasn't the problem. Because my PATH variable already looked like in the guide

Comment: Could you check if 'numpy' folder is there in python packages? C:\Python3x\Libs\site-packages or where ever you have installed python in.

Comment: It is. in C:\Users\Dario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\numpy. I also added that and just C:\Users\Dario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages to PATH as well, just in case

Comment: I just added both version numbers to my question in case that helps, maybe they are not compatible, but I doubt that

Comment: Please see if you have multiple python interpreters in visual studio. Go to View > Other Windows > Python Environments